# Condição de exibição de janela modal Bootstrap com Ajax/Post

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, modal, bootstrap

Criei um método de cadastro de cliente com Ajax via Post. Mas de alguma forma meu código deve conter algum erro quando estabeleço uma certa condição. 
Reparem abaixo: quando o valor retornado de cadastrar.php for "Cadastrado", gostaria que ele abrisse uma determinada janela modal do Bootstrap com a informação de que o cliente foi cadastrado com sucesso. Ocorre que no caso abaixo, ele não deve estar reconhecendo corretamente a expressão, pois está pulando sempre para "else" e abrindo a janela errada. Poderiam me dizer se minha condição "if" contém algum erro?

```js
// Envio dos dados cadastrais do cliente
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#cadastrarcliente').submit(function(){
      var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cadastrar.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function(data) {

       if (data == "Cadastrado")

            $('#enviocliente').modal();

        else  $('#errologinduplicado').modal();
      

        }

        });      
      return false;
    });
  });
```

E o código PHP que retorna a mensagem "Cadastrado"

```html
<?php ob_start();
include("config.php"); //Arquivo configuração do BD

  //Captura todos os dados informados em login.php
$telefixo = $_POST['telefixo'];
$nome = utf8_decode($_POST['nome']);
$rg = utf8_decode($_POST['rg']);
$cpf = utf8_decode($_POST['cpf']);
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$celular = $_POST['celular'];
$cep = $_POST['cep'];
$residencia = $_POST['residencia'];
$endereco = utf8_decode($_POST['endereco']);
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$cidade = utf8_decode($_POST['cidade']);
$uf = $_POST['uf'];
$pessoa = utf8_decode($_POST['pessoa']); 
$datanasc = $_POST['data'];
$estadocivil = $_POST['estadocivil'];
$profissao = utf8_decode($_POST['profissao']);  
$foto = 'anonymous.jpg'; 

$sql_busca = mysqli_query($bd,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE cpf='$cpf'");
$num_busca = mysqli_num_rows($sql_busca);


// Verifica se já não existe uma credencial com mesmo CPF na tabela user
if ($num_busca == 0) {
 

   //Se não existir, grava os dados informados na tabela user
 $sql_inclu = "INSERT INTO user (nome, usuario, senha, email, sexo, celular, cep, residencia, endereco, numero, cidade, uf, estadocivil, profissao, pessoa, datanasc, foto, rg, cpf, telefixo) VALUES ('$nome', '$usuario', '$senha', '$email', '$sexo', '$celular', '$cep', '$residencia', '$endereco', '$numero', '$cidade', '$uf', '$estadocivil', '$profissao', '$pessoa', '$datanasc', '$foto', '$rg', '$cpf', '$telefixo')";
 $exe_inclu = mysqli_query ($bd, $sql_inclu);


 echo "Cadastrado";
}


else {
 
 echo "Erro";

}

?>
```

Comment: Alan, coloque um alert(data); antes do if e veja o que está sendo retornado.

Comment: Se tiver retornando Cadastrado, provavelmente tem algum espaço. Então use na condição assim: if( $.trim(data) ) == "Cadastrado").

Comment: Fiz o alert e ele está me retornando Cadastrado mesmo. Tentei a expressão que você me passou e nada acontece. Não sei onde pode estar o erro.

Comment: Tem como você disponibilizar um pedacinho do código do cadastrar.php que retorna isso?

Comment: Oi Givanildo. Sim, acabei de atualizar o post. Dê uma olhada, por favor.

Comment: Cara, peguei o código seu e aqui pra mim funcionou belezinha. Sinceramente não sei o que pode ser. Coloquei isso console.log('>'+data+'<'); antes do if só pra ver se estava retornando sem espaço ou algum caracter, e tudo certo por aqui.

Comment: Então, pelo que entendi, o problema é que a expressão data == 'Cadastrado' não está sendo interpretado aqui no meu caso. Consegui resolver utilizando numerais, pois como não usa aspas e o javascript consegue reconhecer diretamente, a expressão executa perfeito. Ex: If (data == 1) { ... De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda.